# How to upgrade a JDK module in javac

Tags: java, java-module, java-11

I have some code I need to compile with JDK 11 which uses the Java EE version of the `javax.annotation` package. Specifically, I want to use `@Resource` as a repeatable annotation (Common Annotations 1.3 spec) whereas the annotation is NOT repeatable in JDK 8.  Also, I need to compile this code at a Java 8 bytecode level, as my code still needs to run on JDK 8.

If I compile my code with `javac --release 8`, then I am forced to use the JDK 8 version of `javax.annotations`. Ideally, I would like to use --upgrade-module-path, but `javac` blocks this option:

```
javac --release 8 --upgrade-module-path /path/to/upgraded/module/
error: option --upgrade-module-path cannot be used together with --release
```

In previous Java levels I would prepend my `javax.annotion` jar to the bootclasspath, but this is also blocked with `--release`

```
$ javac --release 8 --boot-class-path foo
error: option --boot-class-path cannot be used together with --release
```

Is there any way to safely compile to an older java level while also overriding/upgrading specific packages/modules?

Comment: do you use any project management tool as Maven or Gradle? It's not hard with them

Comment: In `javac --release 8 --upgrade-module-path /path/to/upgraded/module/`, why do you need  an upgrade module path here? The module that you seem to be looking for is not at all present in the system modules anyway.

Comment: @nullpointer I'm trying to upgrade the `java.xml.ws.annotation` module which was deprecated in JDK 9/10 and removed in JDK 11, however when I do `--release 8` on JDK 11 the `javax.xml.ws.annotation` module seems to be present (or at least the JDK 8 copy of the `javax.annotation` package gets found)

Comment: JDK 8 doesn't know anything about modules. In JDK 8 the endorsed standards override mechanism was the way to compile against the upgraded version of a standalone technology (javac -endorseddirs). I've created a bug to examine if this combination of options should be supported: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212006